# How to Programmatically Create OOXML Strict Documents

Tags: excel, format, spreadsheet, openxml

It is possible to manually save an Excel spreadsheet as a "Strict Open XML" file type in Excel when using "Save as" instead of saving it as the default workbook OOXML file, which is a "Transitional" variant of the OOXML standard. The extension is .xlsx for both Strict and Transitional file format variants of the OOXML standard.

How can I do the same thing programmatically through automated workflows in e.g. C#? The purpose is to bulk convert Transitional Excel files to Strict Excel files.

I have found these code snippets part of the Office XML SDK:

- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.conformanceclass?view=openxml-2.8.1
- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.workbook.conformance?view=openxml-2.8.1#documentformat-openxml-spreadsheet-workbook-conformance

Can I use them or other ways of doing bulk conversion from Transitional to Strict?

**UPDATE:** I am in dialogue with the developers of Open XML SDK in [this issue](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK/issues/1184).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way possible, that I have found after extensive research is to use Excel.Interop and have your Excel installation handle the conversion in the background. It is not a pretty solution, because it is Excel dependent, but it is a programmatic approach.

You can find the Excel.Interop package here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

I had an issue, where the package would not find my Excel installation, so I had to make a new reference to the Excel Interop DLL on your computer.
`Add reference > Browse > C:\Windows\assembly\GAC\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` and pick the DLL from the folder in here. I also added the DLL from the subfolder in this path `C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\office`

**Conversion code**

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

void Convert_Transitional_to_Strict(string input_filepath, string output_filepath)
{
    Excel.Application app = new Excel.Application(); // Create Excel instance
    app.DisplayAlerts = false; // Don't display any Excel prompts
    Excel.Workbook excelWorkbook = app.Workbooks.Open(input_filepath); // Create workbook instance and open Excel Workbook for conversion
    excelWorkbook.SaveAs(output_filepath, 61); // Save file as .xlsx Strict
    excelWorkbook.Close(); // Close the Workbook
    app.Quit(); // Quit Excel Application
}
```

PS. If anyone finds a programmatic approach using Open XML SDK or another C# framework, do still post your answer.